# Finding the limits of automatically-adjusted axes in a MATLAB plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm creating a 2d MATLAB plot. I'm setting the limits of my x axis, and letting my y axis auto-adjust (by setting its limits to [-inf inf]). After creating my plot, I need to check what my y axis has auto adjusted to (as I'm going to create a heatmap to put under my plot).

Unfortunately, ylim (and similar functions) only produce [-inf inf], not whatever the axes have adjusted to.

Some code which reproduces this problem (much more simply than my actual code) is:

```
function createplot(xbounds)
x = xbounds(1):0.5:xbounds(2);
y = x.^2;
plot(x,y);
axis([xbounds,-inf,inf]);

createplot([0,10])
```

which produces a parabolic plot with y limits = [0,100]. However, ylim = [-inf, inf].

Any help would be appreciated!

/ Wilbur

Comment: @Shai is correct, the 3rd and 4th elements of `axis` will return `[0 100]`

Comment: @Shai, for me (Matlab 2012a) it does work, I'll post it as an answer so you'll see the code I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Shai suggested, `axis` can give info regarding the ylimits without the need to set them to `[-inf,inf]` or use axis to set the x-axis bounds:

```
xbounds=[1 10]
x = xbounds(1):0.5:xbounds(2);
y = x.^2;
plot(x,y);
xlim([xbounds(1) xbounds(2)]);
v=axis 

v =
     1    10     0   100
```

Comment: your code is slightly different than @Wilbur's: you only use `xlim` to set the axes, while Wilbur uses `axis` with `[-inf inf]` for `ylim`. It seems like that once you set `ylim` to `[-inf inf]` there's no way back. So, the essence of your answer should be **do not use `[-inf inf]` to set automatic axis limits** but rather skip it all together and use `xlim`, `ylim` or `zlim` to set **only those axes you must configure manually**.

Comment: Sure there is away back, just use `set(gca, 'ylimmode', 'auto')`. However, this will ruin the tight axis limits and replace it by Matlab's normal auto-adjustment.

Comment: @natan - I'm glad you gave me such credit. However, I'm afraid, I was just thinking of adding `v=axis` after `axis( [xbounds -inf inf] )`...

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [@natan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14870186/1714410) I think the solution to your problem is

### Do not use `[-inf inf]` for auto-adjusting axis limits.

If you want Matlab to auto adjust some of your axes limits and manually set others, then you should use either `xlim`, `ylim` or `zlim` for the specific axis you wish to set and **leave all the other unchanged** so Matlab can set them automatically.
This way you will not override the values Matlab assigns to those axes and you will be able to read them using `axis`, `xlim`, `ylim` or `zlim`.

Please see @natan's answer for corrected code.